# Multiple Tables with a single Tabed Form

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

Can you connect multiple tables with a single tabbed form?

For example, if I have 3 tables and I have 1 tabbed form with 3 tabs and I want tab 1 to use table 1, tab 2 to use table 2 and tab 3 to use table 3. Currently, I can only point to one table for the entire tabbed control, thus it appears that all 3 tabs have to share the same record source or table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not exactly a programming question. Yes, you can have as many tables as you have subforms on your tabs. I do not recommend it. I usually find it best to have one or two tabs with subform controls and load forms into the subform controls at runtime, as required.